# Integrating api to navigation tabs in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular10

```
        <div class="card card-primary card-outline card-outline-tabs">
      <div class="card-header p-0 border-bottom-0">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="custom-tabs-three-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let farmingdata of farminginnerdata;let i=index" >
            <a
              class="nav-link" [class.active]="i==0"
              id="{{ farmingdata.id }}"
              href="{{ farmingdata.id }}"
              data-toggle="pill"
              (click)="onContent(farmingdata.id)"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="custom-tabs-three-home"
              aria-selected="true"
              >{{ farmingdata.name }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" *ngIf="farminginnerdata">
        <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-three-tabContent"
         *ngFor="let farmingdata of farminginnerdata ;let i=index">
          <div
            class="tab-pane fade show" [class.active]="i==0"
            [id]="farmingdata.id"

            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-three-Manual-tab">
          <div *ngIf="farmingdata.content; else blankdata" [innerHTML]="farmingdata.content"></div>
          <ng-template #blankdata>No data available </ng-template>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
```

I am a learner in angular ver.10.
I want to integrate API to that nab-tabs.
The issue is when the data first initial loaded, the first tab gets activated and shows its data in tab-content but when I change to another tab, it doesn't show the data.
At what part I have to change or modify, need some help to solve it.

Issue: dynamic data using bootstrap 4 navigation tabs.
Environment: Angular framework ver.10
Attempt: Integrated API to card-header nav tabs, got id when clicked on a particular tab but the card body data not changing.

Comment: i know you are facing difficulties, but if you structure the question like for example {Issue: abc, environment:[angular,react,node,linux], what_i_tried:['attempt1','methodXYZ']} then the person trying to answer your question will find it much easier and you will get help quickly.

Comment: hii @nikhilswami thank you for helping me out, I have updated my data. Please check, if you still didn't understand I will share some image of that output data.